# Can I view the whole map?

Tags: warframe

Is there a way to see the whole level map? The mini-map is pretty nice, but it sometimes get confusing as to where the mission marker actually is during the extraction phase, as it's not placed on the door you need to go through.

I didn't see anything pertaining to the map in the menu, but the game's in beta and maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [no option](https://warframe.com/game/quickstart) to show the full map.

That has a couple of times lead to long games when the path to the exit has not been clear.

Update: They have added a big map that can give you a better overview, you can get it to show by pressing M.

Answer (score 1):

For console players: Press <kbd>Up</kbd> on the d-pad

Answer (score 0):

(-) button in Nintendo Switch for Map (The button with a "-" symbol)

And remember you can re-assign buttons on Switch.